# How to identify a canceled event in Microsoft Graph REST API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

After I've [canceled an event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-cancel?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), I couldn't list it at [List events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-cancel?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) anymore. But it still displaying to end user as subject "Canceled: User subject event". How can I use [List events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to identify this canceled event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [events properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-beta#properties) you will find a "IsCancelled" property you can leverage to filter events out.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Users/xx/Calendar/Events/xx/instances
?startDateTime=2020-02-17&endDateTime=2020-03-01&isCancelled=true
```

and what came back are all the non-cancelled events... Ditto isCancelled=false so the query is kind of working.

leaving off the &isCancelled=xx parameter returns all the events with the isCancelled attribute set to false for everything.